# Navigating pages not working unless on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a GUI application with `WPF` framework.

I have a Window, called MainWindow and a few pages.
I have a menu with buttons, linked to different pages. With this kind of navigation I manage to navigate to different pages and come back home to MainWindow nicely. Example below.

> How I am navigating with buttons - WORKING:

From Window (called MainWindow), to Page (called Settings)

```
private void btnSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings pg = new Settings();
        this.Content = pg;
    }
```

Going back from Page (called Settings), to Window (called MainWindow)

```
private void btnDomov(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Show();
        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        parentWindow.Close();
    }
```

The problem happens when I go to the page from MainWindow, but not with a button click, but as a result of some executed code (in my case when I read an RFID card, I go to "SkenirajKartico" page.). Actually I am able to come to the wanted page, but I am unable to go back to the MainWindow. When I click go to MainWindow (home) it refreshes the same page "SkenirajKartico". The code is shown below. Any Ideas how to solve this issue?

Example: After some code is executed, I am calling a method "pokliciDialog" with intention to go to wanted page ("SkenirajKartico")

> How I am navigating after some code is executed - NOT WORKING

```
private void pokliciDialog()
    {
        if (startup == false)
        {
            SkenirajKartico pg = new SkenirajKartico();
            this.Content = pg;
        }
    }
```

As I said, page is refreshed to wanted page ("SkenirajKartico"). And when some code is executed on this page, I do the same step as above - Calling method "goToMain" to go back Home, but It refreshes current page "SkenirajKartico" and does not go to wanted MainWindow.

```
void goToMain()
{ 
    var MainWindow = new MainWindow();
    MainWindow.Show();
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    parentWindow.Close();
}
```

I see I am missing arguments, but if I add object sender and RoutedEventArgs e to the method, I don't know how to call them. Would be really happy if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, stupid mistake. I was calling method to show the page "SkenirajKartico" each time when MainWindow was loaded. That's why page "SkenirajKartico" was constantly refreshing.
Wooops.